# Inject EJBs to a List by common interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, jndi

I would like to automatically find and inject EJB instances from an EJB container to a List. Example:

```
@EJBs
List<MyCommonInterface> beans;
```

or

```
List<MyCommonInterface> beans;

public MyClass() {
    beans = (List<MyCommonInterface>) context.findBeansByInterface(MyCommonInterface.class);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With JEE6 you can use Instance http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html

With that you use an injected context like

```
@Inject
private Instance<ICommon> ejbs;
```

and you can iterate over it:

```
    for(ICommon c : ejbs)
        c.doSomeThing();
```

here with an example iface like that

```
  public interface ICommon {
      void doSomeThing();   
  }
```

I tested it with SLSB and SFSB in an @Singleton.